# Ошибка при добавлении второй записи в БД

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

Есть несколько Entity:

BaseModel Entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    public abstract class BaseModel {
    
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @Getter
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;
    
        protected BaseModel() {
        }
    }
```

ClassRoom Entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "class_room")
    public final class ClassRoom extends BaseModel {
    
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "classRoom" )
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private List<Teacher> teacher = new ArrayList<>();
    
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "classRoom")
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private List<Pupil> pupil = new ArrayList<>();
    
        @Column(nullable = false)
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String name;
    
        public ClassRoom() {
        }
    }
```

Pupil Entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "pupil")
    public final class Pupil extends BaseModel {
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "pupil_id")
        @Setter
        private ClassRoom classRoom;
    
        @Column(nullable = false)
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String name;
    
        @Getter
        @Setter
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String surname;
        
        public Pupil() {
    
        }
    }
```

Teacher Entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "teacher")
    public final class Teacher extends BaseModel {
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")
        @Setter
        private ClassRoom classRoom;
    
        @Column(nullable = false)
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String name;
    
        @Column(nullable = false)
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String surname;
    
        @Column(nullable = false)
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String discipline;
    
        public Teacher() {
    
        }
    }
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.SchoolJournal.SpringHibernate.model.Pupil.name; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.SchoolJournal.SpringHibernate.model.Pupil.name
```

Тест написанный для тестирования:

```
  @SpringBootTest
  @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
  class SpringHibernateApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  private PupilRepository pupilRepository;

  @Autowired
  private ClassRoomRepository classRoomRepository;

  @Autowired
  private TeacherRepository teacherRepository;

    @BeforeAll
    @Rollback(value = false)
    public void contextLoads() {
        Pupil pupil = new Pupil();
        pupil.setName("Anton");
        pupil.setSurname("Savridov");
    
        Pupil pupil1 = new Pupil();
        pupil.setName("Elena");
        pupil.setSurname("Antonova");
    
        Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
        teacher.setName("Alla");
        teacher.setSurname("Aronova");
        teacher.setDiscipline("Mathematics");
    
        ClassRoom classRoom = new ClassRoom();
        classRoom.setName("1A");
        pupil.setClassRoom(classRoom);
        //classroom.getPupil().add(pupil)
        pupil1.setClassRoom(classRoom);
        //classroom.getPupil().add(pupil1)
        teacher.setClassRoom(classRoom);
    
        classRoomRepository.save(classRoom);
        teacherRepository.save(teacher);
        pupilRepository.save(pupil);
        pupilRepository.save(pupil1);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void createEntity() {
        Iterable<Pupil> allPupil = pupilRepository.findAll();
        for (Pupil pupil1 : allPupil) {
            System.out.println("Ученики");
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
            System.out.println(pupil1.getId() + " " +
                    pupil1.getName() + " " +
                    pupil1.getSurname());
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
        }
    
        Iterable<Teacher> allTeacher = teacherRepository.findAll();
        for (Teacher teacher1 : allTeacher) {
            System.out.println("Учителя");
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
            System.out.println(teacher1.getId() + " " +
                    teacher1.getName() + " " +
                    teacher1.getSurname() + " " +
                    teacher1.getDiscipline());
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
        }
        Iterable<ClassRoom> allClassRoom = classRoomRepository.findAll();
        for (ClassRoom classRoom1 : allClassRoom) {
            System.out.println("Класс");
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
            System.out.println(classRoom1.getId() + " "
                    + classRoom1.getName());
            System.out.println(classRoom1.getPupil().getId() + " " +
                    classRoom1.getPupil().getName() + " " +
                    classRoom1.getPupil().getSurname());
            System.out.println(classRoom1.getTeacher().getId() + " " +
                    classRoom1.getTeacher().getName() + " " +
                    classRoom1.getTeacher().getSurname() + " " +
                    classRoom1.getTeacher().getDiscipline());
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
        }
    }
```

При добавление одной записи все отрабатывает корректно, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: правильно ругается, поле name = null, вы же задаете `pupil.setName("Elena");` а нужно `pupil1.setName("Elena");`, т.е. у другого объекта задается поле, а в объекте `pupil1` остается пустым

Comment: @MrFylypenko увидел ошибку, ох уж эта невнимательность, спасибо